# Using 2 Dockerfiles in Cloud Build to re-use intermediary step image if CloudBuild fails

Tags: dockerfile, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

Cloud Build fails with Timeout Error (I'm trying to deploy CloudRun with Prophet). Therefore I'm trying to split the Dockerfile into two (saving the image in between in case it fails). I'd split the Dockerfile like this:

- Dockerfile_one: python + prophet's dependencies
- Dockerfile_two: image_from_Dockerfile_one + prophet + other dependencies

What should cloudbuild.yaml should look like to:

1. if there is a previously image available skip the step, else run the step with the Dockerfile_one and save the image
2. use the image from the step (1), add more dependencies to it and save the image for deploy

Here is how cloudbuild.yaml looks like right now

```
steps:
#  create gcr source directory
- name: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo 'Creating gcr_source directory for ${_GCR_NAME}'
      mkdir _gcr_source
      cp -r cloudruns/${_GCR_NAME}/. _gcr_source

# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_GCR_NAME}', '.']
  dir: '_gcr_source'

# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_GCR_NAME}']

# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args:
  - run
  - deploy
  - ${_GCR_NAME}
  - --image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_GCR_NAME}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A better design is to keep the thing simple. Have a pipeline that build your base image, that you run when required. And another pipeline that use this base image and do its job. A separation of concern is always better, simpler, smarter.

Comment: Makes sense. I understand how to save the build image in the first pipeline. How to build from that image in the 2nd one?

Comment: If you same your build image with this name (for example in Container Registry) `gcr.io/projectid/baseimage`, simply start your `Dockerfile` with this same image `FROM gcr.io/projectid/baseimage`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks! that's what I needed. I didn't know I could specify gcr.io/* images in FROM. I managed to split the build onto two Dockerfiles.
On Python 3.9 it didn't work anyway though. Looks like pystan doesn't go well with Python3.9. On python3.8 everything works fine even with 1 Dockerfile, but at the end of the day it was a good learning exercise.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 pipelines

1. The first one create the base image. Like that, you can trigger it everytime that you need to rebuild this base image, with, possibly a different lifecycle than your application lifecycle. Something similar to that

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/base-image', '-f', 'DOCKERFILE_ONE', '.']
images: ['gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/base-image']
```

2. Then, in your second dockerfile, start from the base image and use a second Cloud Build pipeline to build, push and deploy it (as you do in your 3 last steps in your question)

```
FROM gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/base-image
COPY .....
....
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally managed to do that and the build time dropped x5

Comment: And to anybody coming here CloudBuild Python3.9 with pystan doesn't seem to go well anyway. Looks like pystan==2.19.1.1 works with Python3.8 only when built with GCB

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but as a workaround. If anybody has the same issue, using Python3.8 instead 3.9 worked for Cloud Build.

This what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

# Install pystan
RUN pip install Cython>=0.22
RUN pip install numpy>=1.7
RUN pip install pystan==2.19.1.1

# Install other prophet dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install prophet
```

Though figuring out how to iteratively build images for CloudRun, would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

Why did your Cloud Build fail with Timeout Error ?

While building images in docker, it  is important to keep the image size down. Often multiple dockerfiles are created to handle the image size constraint. In your case, you were not able to reduce the image size and include only what is needed.

What can be done to rectify it ?

- As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-building-containers#reduce_the_amount_of_clutter_in_your_image), multi-stage builds, (introduced in
  Docker 17.05) allows you to build your app in a first "build"
  container and use the result in another container, while using the
  same Dockerfile.
- You use multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile. Each FROM
  instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new
  stage of the build. You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage
  to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final
  image. To show how this works, follow this [link](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds).
- You only need a single Dockerfile.
- The result is the same tiny production image as before, with a
  significant reduction in complexity. You don’t need to create any
  intermediate images and you don’t need to extract any artifacts to
  your local system at all.

How does it work?

- You can [name your build stages](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages). By default, the stages are not
  named, and you refer to them by their integer number, starting with 0
  for the first FROM instruction. However, you can name your stages, by
  adding an AS  to the FROM instruction.
- When you build your image, you don’t necessarily need to build the
  entire Dockerfile including every stage. You can specify a [target
  build stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage).
- When using multi-stage builds, you are not limited to copying from
  stages you created earlier in your Dockerfile. You can use the
  COPY --from instruction to [copy from a separate image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage),either
  using the local image name, a tag available locally or on a Docker
  registry, or a tag ID.
- You can [pick up where a previous stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage) left off by referring
  to it when using the FROM directive.
- In the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-building-containers#reduce_the_amount_of_clutter_in_your_image), there is an example of dockerfile
  which uses multi-stage builds. The hello binary is built in a first
  container and injected in a second one. Because the second container
  is based on [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/scratch/), the resulting image contains only the hello
  binary and not the source file and object files needed during the
  build.

> ```
> FROM golang:1.10 as builder
>
> WORKDIR /tmp/go
> COPY hello.go ./
> RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -ldflags '-s' -o hello
>
> FROM scratch
> CMD [ "/hello" ]
> COPY --from=builder /tmp/go/hello /hello
> ```

- Here is a [tutorial](http://padok.fr/en/blog/docker-image-multi-staging) to understand how multi staging builds work.